# Invalid object name 'dbo.Languages'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am very new with stored procedure. Today, first time I am working with stored procedure.

I have a table in sql server named- Languages. Which has fields- **Id, Name, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy, IsDelete**.

I have made a stored procedure, but don't know how to use it in project.

My stored procedure is-

```
    USE [HRMS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[hrm_Add]    Script Date: 04/30/2014 15:06:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hrm_Add] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Id int = 0, 
    @Name varchar(120),
    @CreatedOn datetime,
    @UpdatedOn datetime=0,
    @CreatedBy bigint=0,
    @UpdatedBy bigint=0,
    @IsDeleted bit=0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [dbo.Languages](Name, CreatedOn,UpdatedOn,CreatedBy,UpdatedBy,IsDeleted) VALUES(@Name,@CreatedOn,@UpdatedOn,@CreatedBy,@UpdatedBy,@IsDeleted)
END
```

My project code on click is-

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strcon);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("hrm_Add", sqlConnection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
        command.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedBy", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1;
        command.Parameters.Add("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am getting error that **Invalid object name 'dbo.Languages'.**

How can I solve it.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the connectionstring? Perhaps you are connecting to another server or database.

Comment: check the connection string is going to HRMS, and that the actual SP has been run against that DB.

Comment: Yes, connected with wrong db.. Silly mistake.

Comment: Now getting error--- Invalid object name 'dbo.Languages'.

Comment: Make sure you have table `dbo.Languages` in current database

Comment: [dbo.Languages] should be [dbo].[Languages]

Comment: @KevinMain Post this as an answer

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the suggestions in the comments make sure you are connecting to the correct database first.

Then you will need to change

```
[dbo.Languages]
```

to

```
[dbo].[Languages]
```

FYI: The reason for this is that SQL Server uses a fully qualified name to reference objects such as

```
[server_name].[database_name].[schema_name].[object_name]
```

In general when you refer to an object, you do not have to specify the server, database, and owner.

In your case you are specifying the owner name as dbo but the syntax is incorrect - you need to be using dot notation such as

```
[schema_name].[object_name]
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining why this is the case (object names and schemas etc.), would make a first class answer then =]